# How we can implement a "Bell Notification" inside asp.net mvc-6 core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, push-notification, signalr

I am working on an asp.net core web application, and our system has a lot of functionality to assign items to registered users where i want to notify the users about these items, by implementing a Bell-like notification (which is been used by a lot of social media site), as follow:-

[image]

now at this stage i am trying to understand how these notifications work behind the scenes, as after we check the notification we will not get any pending items. so from my understanding it works as follow:-

1. i need to have a javascript inside my page, which will check our database for all the notification assigned to the user + which have not been read before.
2. then to show the the number as shown above.
3. if the user click on the Bell to check the pending items >> post requests should be sent to our back-end, to update these pending items that they have been read by the user?

I am not sure if those notifications work in this way? and are there any tutorials describing how we can have a Bell-Like real time notifications?

Comment: There's no MVC 6, please stop calling it like that. ASP.NET Core hasn't be called like this in over 3 years

Comment: @Tseng ok i updated my question.. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is far too broad to be reasonably answered, but generally:

- You don't need JavaScript at all if you're fine with it only updating on page refresh/change. For example, if this was part of your site layout, then it would load on every page. As the user navigates around the site, the bell would update based on the current count of notifications each time a new page was requested by the user. However, if they remained on the same page for an extended period of time, they would not be made aware of any further new notifications. That's not necessarily an issue, though. Many sites behave like this.
- If you *do* want immediate updates, then you'll need to utilize SignalR (websockets). Server-side, you'll create a hub and client-side, you'll subscribe to a particular message type from this hub (JavaScript). When something happens that the user needs to be notified of, a new message of that type will be sent through the hub, which will immediately go out to the subscribed client(s). The client-side subscription callback will then be invoked, allowing you to do stuff like dynamically update the count of notifications (more JavaScript).
- Regardless of which method you choose, you'll be best served by creating a view component for this server-side. That will allow you to encapsulate the logic of querying the database for notifications and the rendering of the bell all together and then simply drop this into your layout, for example.
- If there's a client-side to this (i.e. for the immediate updates), you'd likely also want to employ some sort of component there (via Vue.js, React, Angular, etc. - each has their own "components"). That will allow you to similarly encapsulate all the logic for this in one easily reusable container.

Comment: ok thanks for the info... will check these solutions.. but what about hiding/removing the Bell notification number when users read them ? are those actually post requests sent from the Bell to the back-end, to update the status of the notification to be Read,, so no pending number will be shown? or this will be handled automatically for us if we use SignalR for example?

Comment: Well, that would involve JavaScript at that point, but could be done without SignalR. In fact, even with SignalR, it could still be done with or without it. Just depends on how you want to handle it.

Comment: yes i know now on paper i can create something from scratch to implement the Bell-like notifications,, but i am trying to find if there are architecture approaches i can follow instead of re-inviting the wheel... i am talking about the architecture of such functionalities... for example not sure how the inbox inside stackoverflow implements this..

Comment: The "not reinventing the wheel" part comes in using things like view components, SignalR, Vue/React/Angular components, etc. However, there's no drop-in "here's a bell for notifications" thing. You still need to write code to wire everything up, handle the UI/UX, etc. That's not reinventing the wheel - that's just doing what you're paid to do: program.

Comment: yes of course, even if i use SignalR i have to write a code. but i am talking about the technical architecture of such a functionality. is it for example a post request which the Bell will send to the backend to update the status of these notification as READ? or it is more like updating the session data? or by using TempData, etc. this what i am asking for.. for example when i first implement the confirmation messages inside asp.net MVC i read that using TempData is the way to go, then i have/need to implement it.

Comment: so i meant that i do not want to re-invite the wheel from a technical architecture point of view..

Comment: It depends on the specific use case. TempData is only really for transitory notifications, like something being saved successfully - things that don't need to be persisted. If you want persistent notifications, then you need to use the database. You need someway to get a list of all notifications, and to mark one or more as read. That could be just a method on a service class or an API endpoint, or both. SignalR just enables to two-way communication; it has nothing to do really with the core implementation.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt thanks for your answer. I am thinking of picking up the correct technology. So far, I have found SignalR, Service Bus(Topic/Subscribtion), Notification Hub etc. I am confused about which one to choose. Could you please shed light on this? thanks

Comment: It's all pretty much the same. SignalR is specifically geared towards real-time communication. A service bus, message broker, etc. are for generalized messaging. That can include real-time or more advanced scenarios. It really just depends on what you need. If all you're doing is this, then SignalR is the easiest and most straight-forward, but if you need a message broker, anyways, you can also use it for this.